# python html print identation issue

Tags: python, html

for a cgi script the output if run in shell will look like this:

```
device1       data :              10000 Bps             100000 pps
device2       data :                100 Bps                100 pps
```

Unfortunately when i print it in my html after the script does it's job , indentation will not be kept , i'm looking for a simple workaround if possible , since i print in a "for" loop:

```
for line in data.splitlines() :
    print "<p> %s-data: %s</p>" % (device , data)
```

Output in html:

```
device1       data :10000 Bps 100000 pps
device2       data :100 Bps 100 pps
```

Solved:

```
print "<style>"
print"p {white-space:pre-wrap}"
print "</style>"
```

Comment: Can you share the javascript code where you are adding this contents in the HTML

Comment: no js , plain html that i print from the python cgi script.

Comment: Yeah that's why this problem occurs. because normally HTML will eliminate all the white spaces. Ok check the answer below

Comment: why don't you use html tables to format the output?

Comment: If i use tables , i need to make more prints from the python script , that will overcomplicate things , it's the last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally HTML will eliminate the whitespaces between words.

To avoid that you can assign the following css property to the
**PARENT** element of your contents

`white-space:pre;`

Add this style on the parent element(div) of your content

Let me know if it is helpful

Comment: Indeed pre solves the issue , but creates another one: i get empty rows between the printed ones, i also tried white-space:pre-wrap with no success.